# Executing an animation with for loop in callback function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Inside `updateMapColor` function, the world map changes colors based on the input year's value. I am trying to animate the color change over a sequence of years by calling `updateMapColor`, but it's not working.

Do I need to use `setInterval`, if so why? Could someone explain the underlying issue please?

```
d3.select('body').append('button').attr({
    class: "button",
    id: "animateMap"
})
    .text("Animate the map")
    .on("click", function (d) {
        for (i = 0; i < yearArray.length; i++) {
            updateMapColor[yearArray[i]]
        }
    })

var updateMapColor = function (y) {
    year = y;
    var rankingList = {}
    coloredWorldMap.transition().duration(700).attr('fill', function (d) {
        a = d;
        x = d3.values(tennis).filter(function (d) {
            return (d.DATE == year)
        })
        rankingList = x;

        x = d3.values(x).filter(function (d) {
            return (d.COUNTRY_ID == a.id)
        })

        if (x.length != 0) {
            if (x[0].COUNT == 0) {
                return "#fff"
            }
            else {
                return colorScale(x[0].COUNT)
            }
        }

        else {
            return '#fff'
        }

        return colorScale(x[0].COUNT)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem in javascript: trying to call a function inside a `for` loop with some delay.

The reason your code doesn't work is simple: the `for` loop will run almost immediately (in just a few miliseconds for a hundred or so loops), and **all** the calls to `updateMapColor` will happen almost simultaneously.

There are different ways to fix this. One of my favourite solutions is using an IIFE:

```
(function loop(i) {
    if (i++ >= (yearArray.length - 1)) return;
    setTimeout(function() {
        updateMapColor(i);
        loop(i)
    }, 500)
})(-1);
```

**Explanation:**

This IIFE will run for the first time with `i = -1`. Then, the if increases `i` (doing i++, which makes `i` effectively starting at 0, just like in your `for` loop) and checks if it is equal or bigger than `yearArray.length - 1`. If it is, the function `loop` returns. If it's not, a `setTimeout` is scheduled, which calls `updateMapColor` and the very function `loop` again.

Check the demo, with a `setInterval` of 0.5 seconds:

```js
var yearArray = d3.range(20);

(function loop(i) {
    if (i++ >= (yearArray.length - 1)) return;
    setTimeout(function() {
        updateMapColor(i);
        loop(i)
    }, 500)
})(-1);

function updateMapColor(index){
 console.log("The function was called with i = " + index);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**PS**: whatever you're trying to do, it'd be way easier just chaining a bunch of D3 transitions.